# ajax loading file with slideToggle effect

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am loading text files in div container, and I've made it work so far.
What I wish now is to animate it with slideToggle effect. This is what the webpage looks like:

```
<div id="content" style="width: 75%">
    <?php
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator('uploads/temp') as $file)
    {
        if(!$file->isDot())
        {
           echo '<a href="#" onmousedown="javascript:ajax.query(
           \'view.php?file=uploads/temp/'.$file.'\',\'file\')">'.$file.'</a> ';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="file" style="text-align: justify"></div>
</div>
```

How to apply slideToggle function to links? You can check the actual webpage [HERE](http://skolarasta.site88.net/dev.php)

Many thanks

Comment: A few questions: You're including jQuery in your page, but you're using another solution for your AJAX requests. Any particular reason why? Are you planning on using jQuery for the mentioned effect? Do you have an example on what exactly you want it to look like?

Comment: thanks for replying. jquery is there at the moment just to use it's slide function. i have some free time and i am just playing around with trying to understand javascript slightly better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to attach a callback event to your ajax request, so that the slide animation does not occur until the content has loaded. To do so using jQuery's built-in ajax and event functionality would look like this:

```
<?php foreach... {
    // Removed onmousedown, as the event is now attached using pure jQuery
    echo '<a href="#">'.$file.'</a> ';
} ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Attach click event listener to all links inside id="content"
$("#content a").live("click", function(e)
{
    // Perform a simple Ajax call based on link contents
    $.get('view.php?file=uploads/temp/'+$(this).text(), function(html)
    {
        // Hide div, populate content, and perform animation
        $("#file")
            .hide()
            .html(html)
            .slideDown();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: many thanks, this is exactly what i wanted. but now please can you tell me how to do this without jquery?? let's imagine there is a working slideToggle function